# What is the difference between "new DOMParser();" and "( new window.DOMParser() )"

Tags: javascript, jquery, eslint

What is the difference between the set of code from jquery V-2.1.3 & jquery V-3.5.1

from jquery-2.1.3
`tmp = new DOMParser(); xml = tmp.parseFromString( data, "text/xml" );` 
and jquery-3.5.1
`xml = ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString( data, "text/xml" );`

Comment: There could be a different `DOMParser` defined which is not the global one.

Comment: Should be nothing. Did you take a look at the source code repository to find why they changed it?

Comment: End result is that it's the same,  the second removes the temp variable and forces to `window.DOMParser` (reason above by @VLAZ)

Comment: ESLintScanJS RulesCall parseFromString is showing it a vulnerability when using in version Jquery 2.1.3